# Buttons not recognizing taps when added to view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am trying to add a subview with buttons to my view after the scroll view reaches certain y offset. While adding the view works flawless, and buttons are added, I cannot make them recognize taps and perform selectors.

Do you guys have any idea what may cause this behavior? Any help would be greately appreciated.

Comment: What's the view hierarchy like? i.e. could there be a view in front of your subview with buttons that is interfering with user interaction?

Comment: More likely the buttons are outside their superview.

Comment: Show some code. Is your subview user interaction enabled?

Comment: Thanks, I've just dealt with the issue - because the subview is on the very top of the view, where navigation bar usually sits, I had to put the view on top of the navigation bar's view. I did it with code: `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:self.myView];`

Comment: May be but not sure you can also try `[yourView bringSubviewToFront:yourButton];`

Comment: That doesn't work. The only way to make my bar recognize views is either to fully remove the navigation bar from the view (which messes up my layout a bit) or use the code I provided in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

My subview was placed where the navigation bar usually sits. I had to make sure that my view is on top of it (and everything else, in fact) by using the code:

`[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:myView];`, where my view is a subview that I wanted to be on top.

Answer (score 0):

I think it due to some gesture conflict, so can you try to implement `- gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` delegate method, like this :

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

  // check if the view is button
  if([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
       return NO;
   }
   // check if the superview is button
   if([touch.view.superview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
       return NO;
   }
   // check if the superView of superview is button
   if([touch.view.superview.superview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
       return NO;
   }
   return YES;
}
```